# git-svn: git svn rebase does not update repo

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I can successfully fetch the svn repo via `git init` + `git svn fetch`.  But when I try to update or pull the svn repo updates to my local git-svn repo via `git svn rebase` I keep getting *Current branch trunk is up to date*.

**EDIT**
Does it make a difference if I've already pushed modifications to a git repo?

Below is my `.git/config` file.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://server/svn/Project
    fetch = SubProject/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    tags = SubProject/tags/{1.03.000,1.02.000}:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

Comment: Are you sure there are new commits in the SVN repository that you do not already have in your Git clone? `git svn rebase` should do exactly what you expect.

Comment: @Vampire there are definitely updates. I tried switching to the trunk branch, git svn fetch --all + git svn rebase.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **fetch the new commits from the SVN repository first** then rebase the same with the local `Git` repository, clean and push it to the remote, as follows:

```
D:\svn-to-git\dev-git> git svn fetch
D:\svn-to-git\dev-git> java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar D:\svn-to-git\svn-migration-scripts.jar sync-rebase
D:\svn-to-git\dev-git> java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar D:\svn-to-git\svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git --force
D:\svn-to-git\dev-git> git add .
D:\svn-to-git\dev-git> git push
```

More you can read here - [Migrating From SVN to Git](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/migrating-from-svn-to-git/).

Comment: Besides that `git-svn` is not really the right tool for a migration from SVN to Git, but only for using Git as frontend to an SVN server to which you want to commit back, why shouldn't `git svn rebase` be enough? `git svn fetch` will update all branches that are cloned, but as you can read in the first sentence of the documentation of `git svn rebase`: "This fetches revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD and rebases the current (uncommitted to SVN) work against it." So should exactly do what OP wants.

Comment: I thought git svn rebase is the equivalent of svn update? I did try git svn fetch just to see if it would pull the changes from the SVN repo but that has seemed to as well.

Comment: @Vampire the difference between `git svn rebase` and `git svn fetch` AFAIU in the fact that former "fetches revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD", whereas the latter fetches all untracked revisions from the svn remote. Besides `git-svn` is a very good tool for the smooth migration, worked many times in different setups for me, and the edge cases where it didn't could safely be ignored or if not - then yes, look at the more sophisticated alternatives.

Comment: @MykolaGurov I know the difference. The point is that OPs usage should be fine and get the updates he expects. Thus the answer is not correct as it suggests OP should first fetch all updates which should not be necessary as `git svn rebase` first fetches the revisions it needs to do its work. I don't want to start a discussion in comments here about the pros and cons of `git svn` for migration, I just shared the experience I have and it is not only bad in edge cases. e.g. that tags are not tags is fine for using as frontend but bad for migration and there are other points too.

Comment: @RishiPatel you are right, `git svn rebase` *is* the equivalent of `svn update` and should work fine. That's why I said that this answer is misleading and wrong.